# Mapping a custom subdomain ONLY with managed certificates on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am confused about the process for adding a custom subdomain *only* for App Engine, where App Engine manages the certificates. I'm following the steps in Google's documentation but this is messing up the mapping for my root domain. I want api.mydomain.com to point to my app engine instance, but the root of my domain and www. point to a website hosted on a different service. Note when I started this process I already had these DNS records:

- `@ - A - <an IP address where I'm serving my root domain>`
- `www - CNAME - mydomain.com`

Going through the process in the app engine console it told me to add 4 A and 4 AAAA records at the *root* (i.e. @), and then a CNAME for my subdomain, e.g. after this was done I had

- `@ - A - <an IP address where I'm serving my root domain>`
- `@ - A - 216.239.32.21`
- `@ - A - 216.239.34.21`
- `@ - A - 216.239.36.21`
- `@ - A - 216.239.38.21`
- `@ - AAAA - 2001:4860:4802:32::15`
- `@ - AAAA - 2001:4860:4802:34::15`
- `@ - AAAA - 2001:4860:4802:36::15`
- `@ - AAAA - 2001:4860:4802:38::15`
- `www - CNAME - mydomain.com.`
- `api - CNAME - ghs.googlehosted.com.`

The problem though is now some users, when they go to mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com, are getting App Engine's 404 page. This would seem to make sense because the A and AAAA records I added for App Engine are at the '@' level.

Does anyone know what is wrong about this setup? Is it not possible to use managed certificates on a subdomain only on App Engine?

Comment: It is indeed possible to use managed certificates for subdomains, have you tried setting this in your `dispatch.yaml` as explained in [this article](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2017/10/15/google-app-engine-using-subdomains/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just linking a subdomain to App Engine you should not add the A and AAAA records for the base domain `@`

If you remove the Google A and AAAA records your setup should work as expected.

Comment: My understanding is that the A and AAAA records are needed for Google to manage the SSL certificates.

Comment: They are only required if you are using the base domain. If it is just sub domains, you only need to add the cname for the sub domain you are using.